# Spring configuration properties hint not appearing while defining them in application yml file

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I was just experimenting with type-safe configuration properties in Spring Boot using IntelliJ as ID. I am facing issues with getting hint while defining those properties inside the applicatin.yml file. Hint works perfectly fine as long as its simple POJO not with the collection of beans. For Example: with respect to the below code, when I specify the the properties for admins inside the application.yml file, I just get rest-api.admins as the hint. It doesn't guide me to specify the property of internal object inside the collection.
[image]
 Here is  my sample code:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(
        prefix = "rest-api",
        ignoreUnknownFields = true
)
@Component
public class RestApiProperties {

    private static final List<Person> DEFAULT_ADMIN = Arrays.asList(defaultAdmin());

    @NestedConfigurationProperty
    private Person person = new Person();

    private List<Person> admins = DEFAULT_ADMIN;


    public Person getPerson() {
        return person;
    }

    public List<Person> getAdmins() {
        return admins;
    }

    public void setAdmins(List<Person> admins) {
        this.admins = admins;
    }

    private static Person defaultAdmin() {
        Person person = new Person();
        person.setName("defaultAdmin");
        person.setAge(34);
        person.setSex(MALE);
        return person;
    }
```

And have my pojo Person in different class:

```
public class Person {
    private static final String DEFAULT_NAME = "defaultUser";
    private static final int DEFAULT_AGE = 23;
    private static final Sex DEFAULT_SEX = Sex.MALE;

    private String name = DEFAULT_NAME;
    private int age = DEFAULT_AGE;
    @NestedConfigurationProperty
    private Sex sex = DEFAULT_SEX;

    public Sex getSex() {
        return sex;
    }

    public void setSex(Sex sex) {
        this.sex = sex;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

Below Enum class for Sex

```
public enum Sex {
    MALE, FEMALE
}
```

I have added additional-spring-configuration-metadata.json and placed inside the META-INF folder.

```
{
  "groups": [
    {
      "name": "rest-api",
      "type": "yadavsudhir405.rest.github.com.configurationProperty.RestApiProperties"
    },
    {
      "name": "rest-api.person",
      "type": "yadavsudhir405.rest.github.com.configurationProperty.Person"
    }
  ],
  "properties": [
    {
      "name": "rest-api.person.name",
      "type": "java.lang.String"
    },
    {
      "name": "rest-api.person.age",
      "type": "java.lang.Integer"
    },
    {
      "name": "rest-api.person.sex",
      "type": "yadavsudhir405.rest.github.com.configurationProperty.Sex"
    },
    {
      "name": "rest-api.admins",
      "type": "java.util.List<yadavsudhir405.rest.github.com.configurationProperty.Person>"
    }

  ],
  "hints": []
}
```

Comment: What I want is,  when I specify each item of collection, intellij should guide and check the data-type of each item of the collection.

Comment: There is related request on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-151708